# How to get count of how many time indexpath is called in CollectionView in iOS?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have to select any two data from array in collectionView. After clicking any two data collectionview should hide.

So how to check how many times my indexpath is called? How to check my collectionview cell is called two time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - First take new array variable.
2 - append selected record in new array in didSelectItemAtIndexpath
3 - Check the count of new array in didSelectItemAtIndexpath, if count of new array is equal to 2, then hide collection view and take two records from new array.

Comment: i have different section with different data.can you please show me code?